# 2.5/3D world/street

Tags: javascript, html, 2d

I am trying to create a world, or rather a street in a First Person perspective using `html5`, without `WebGL`.

Unfortunately I can not find any engine that I could use. Does anybody know an engine that will do this, or will I have to write the engine myself?

Comment: How did you try to search? Google seems to offer [lots of results that seem to cover your task](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+3d+engine+-webgl).

Comment: why would you not want to use webGL for 3D, other alternative are likely more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had fairly decent success with [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/)

At the time I was looking at canvas and 3D this was the only one that stood out. Easily allows you to switch between canvas rendering and WebGL rendering, and there are *plenty* of examples to check out in the above link.

I was hoping to just use the Canvas rendering, but ran into performance issues with he amount of objects in the scene and moved onto using [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/). That's another kettle of fish, but you might run into the same issue depending on your scene's assets.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What does it allow you to do? How does it compare with other libraries? Does it have any specific problems?